# Angular Material responsive scrollable div

Tags: angularjs, responsive, angularjs-material

I'm trying to make a component with repeated objects similar to the ones labelled "Design," "Development," etc. [in this example](http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/scrumboard/boards/32gfhaf2/acme-frontend-application). I want it to respond to the window height the same way as these (notice that when you shrink your page vertically, the footers go up also). Basically, the scrollable section (perhaps md-content?) needs to be responsive.

This is my current general layout: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yroc92/wyexmckz/).

```
    <body>
      <div class="header">My nav bar</div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="myfeed">
            <div class="feed-header">Feed header</div>
            <div class="feed-content">
              <div class="item">item 1</div>
              <div class="item">item 2</div>
              <div class="item">item 3</div>
              <div class="item">item 4</div>
              <div class="item">item 5</div>
              <div class="item">item 6</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: Assume that items result from an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
.item {
  background-color: yellow;
  height:8vh;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

You need to change `height: 8vh` depending on the number of elements.

Comment: But what if items are the result of an ng-repeat?

Comment: so you need to set vh dynamically(x/items.length).